# What cd expect from me in this case?

Tags: bash

Let's say I inputs the following command:

```sh
cd "C:\Users\Windows\YandexDisk\Programming\Git\Test\"
```

But after it git [prints `>` symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iweNs.png) and I don't know what I have to do. If I omit the last `\` everything is normal. Why it happens?

Comment: Why are you typing that?

Comment: I want to understand when I have to use backslash and when not.

Comment: *"I want to understand when I have to use back"* - It is explained in the bash manual.  Run "man bash" and search for "QUOTING" (in caps).

Answer (score 2):

You are not inside git, you are inside a shell provided by your Git installation.

This happens because your shell is Bash and in Bash, all command lines have a single valid grammar. `\` inside double-quoted strings is the escape character, so your double-quoted string is not terminated.

You should instead single-quote your path:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Winodws\YandexDisk\Programming\Git\Test\'
```

This will work (does not work inside CMD).

Inside CMD, programs compiled with the default C runtime tokenize their command line themselves and `\` is allowed as the last character of an argument.